# Flux and ParseReact - Should I create actions and stores?

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs, flux

I am new to parse.com and react.  All of the samples I've seen are based on Flux with actions and stores.  ParseReact uses observe() and mutators in the react components.  Does this violate the flux model and remove the benefits of encapsulation of the stores?  Should I somehow create actions and stores with ParseReact?

Answer (score 0):

ParseReact implements its querying and subscription interface in a similar way to how relay is designed to work with a react component. The advantage is that you get to specify exactly the data each component needs, rather than using a controller view wired to a store which will pass down all data to every component under it. And also similarly to Relay, ParseReact uses a global store so that it can keep every subscription updated in every component across the app.

So if you are just using data from Parse, there doesn't seem to be a need to wire up stores. However, if you are creating local application state from a combination of remote and local data, the flux pattern may still be necessary. For example, maybe you want to have a set of app-wide configuration options. They would likely be set in a settings panel somewhere, and use the flux pattern to change state across the entire app.